# URL blocked by whitelist: in ionic app whitelist plugin already added

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, url, whitelist, blocked

My app URL is getting blocked by whitelist, I have already added a whitelist plugin and Necessary changes in config.xml but still, it couldn't be resolved.
Any Help would much be appreciated.
This is my ionic info
[image]

Comment: Make sure to include your plugin config, version, and how you added a whitelist plugin. May help to also include the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem of whitelist severally, mostly when building Android app, even after adding the plug-in and necessary update in config.xml, but i was able to solve it in different occasions with the following;

1. Adding the base URL(e.g https://testapi.com or http://192.168.1.100) of your API or Back-end project to the ***network_security_config.xml*** file of your android project, the file is located in ***Platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml*** directory of your project, below is an example

   [image: network_security_config]
2. If your url is **http** and not **https** or your base URL is not on regular post 80 e.g http://67.1.4.2:40, you might want to test your application with another **ISP**(*Internet Service Provider*) and if it happens to work with other **ISP**, then you should consider changing your URL to **https** and pointing a domain name to your IP.

Comment: Please note for option 1 above, when you remove your android platform and re-add again, you may have to recheck your network_security_config.xml file.